# Script execution policy

Tags: powershell, signing, executionpolicy

I have a PowerShell execution policy problem. At first I thought it was just because I was trying to run a script from a GitHub project, but I can't even run my own scripts. I didn't have this problem in the past, and I don't know what could have changed between then and now.

```
> script.ps1 cannot be loaded because the exe
cution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing"
 for more details.
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to check and potentially adjust the current policy for both the x86 and x64 versions of PowerShell  (if applicable).

Use `Get-ExecutionPolicy` to check the current policy, and adjust accordingly with `Set-ExecutionPolicy`.

Refer to *[Using the Set-ExecutionPolicy Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee176961(v=technet.10))* for a description of the execution policies.

Comment: I did that and it's still showing the same error. I set it to Unrestricted

Comment: Set it to `Bypass` or do RMB\Properties\Unblock on the script.

Comment: Oh, yes, and check in both x86 and x64 PS consoles.